# replace data if string left equals to something in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So i have a dataset looks like:

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nanana | Teacher | 123456 |
| Popopo | Student | 232322 |
| Cecece | Teacher | 455433 |
| Lalala | Student | 231231 |
| Poasls | Teacher | 235433 |
| Lilili | Teacher | 723543 |

I wanted to replace **COL A** When

> Col B = Teacher AND LEFT(**COL C**,1) = 2/4

I wanted to replace it if teacher and number = 2/4 Then Teacher2
I wanted to replace it if teacher and number = 1 Then Teacher
Else Existing data keep.

LEFT(**COL B**,1) = Substring of the first number in COL C.

expected output will be

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Teacher | Teacher | 123456 |
| Popopo | Student | 232322 |
| Teacher2 | Teacher | 455433 |
| Lalala | Student | 231231 |
| Teacher2 | Teacher | 235433 |
| Lilili | Teacher | 723543 |

Comment: Can you give an expected output dataframe?

Comment: Added more data into dataset and expected output @Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with masks:

```
# filter Teacher in Col B
m1 = df['Col B'].eq('Teacher')

#first letter 2 or 4 in Col C
s = df['Col C'].astype(str).str[0]
m2 = s.isin(['2','4'])
#first letter 1
m3 = s.eq('1')

df['Col A'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & m3], ['Teacher2','Teacher'], default=df['Col A'])
print (df)
      Col A    Col B   Col C
0   Teacher  Teacher  123456
1    Popopo  Student  232322
2  Teacher2  Teacher  455433
3    Lalala  Student  231231
4  Teacher2  Teacher  235433
5    Lilili  Teacher  723543
```